# If user value price percentage is 30% less than inputted value

Tags: php

Okay I am trying to work out a math equation in PHP with no avail. Here's what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$staticprice = '345.00'; //always the same
$uservalue = $_POST['value'];
if($uservalue is 30% or less than $staticprice){ die();}
```

So I don't want user's value to be 30% or less than the static price.

How would I go by accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($uservalue <= ($staticprice * 0.3))
   die();
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$staticprice = 345.00; //always the same
$uservalue = $_POST['value'];
if($uservalue <= ($staticprice * 0.3)){ die();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple math:

```
$staticprice = '345.00'; //always the same
$uservalue = $_POST['value'];
if($uservalue / $staticprice * 100 == 30 || $uservalue  < $staticprice){ die();}
```

But you don't even have to check if it is equal to 30 percentage. Because if you also want the if statement to be true if `$uservalue` is less then `$staticprice` you only have to write this:

```
$staticprice = '345.00'; //always the same
$uservalue = $_POST['value'];
if($uservalue  < $staticprice){ die();}
```

Comment: == 30? that will be true in 1% of all cases.

Comment: @neokio OP wrote that i pseudo code: `$uservalue is 30%`, But since he also wrote: `or less than $staticprice` He only has to check if the uservalue is less then the staticprice